# How to find out difference of two dataframes in terms of column name using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to find out the difference between two data frame in terms of column names.

This is sample table1

```
d1 = {'row_num': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'name': ['john', 'tom', 'bob', 'rock', 'jimy'], 'DoB': ['01/02/2010', '01/02/2012', '11/22/2014', '11/22/2014', '09/25/2016'], 'Address': ['NY', 'NJ', 'PA', 'NY', 'CA']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
df1['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['DoB']).month
df1['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['DoB']).year
```

This is sample table2

```
d2 = {'row_num': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'name': ['john', 'tom', 'bob', 'rock', 'jimy'], 'DoB': ['01/02/2010', '01/02/2012', '11/22/2014', '11/22/2014', '09/25/2016'], 'Address': ['NY', 'NJ', 'PA', 'NY', 'CA']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

table 2 or df2 does not have the month and year column like df1. I want to find out which columns of df1 are missing in df2.

I know there's 'EXCEPT' in sql but how to do it using pandas/python , Any suggestions ?

Comment: Do you simply want the *names* of the columns? Or do you want the columns themselves?

Comment: For now I need the column names. Although it'd be good to know if there's a way to get the column values too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a function meant just for this purpose: [`pd.Index.difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html)

```
df1.columns.difference(df2.columns)
Index(['month', 'year'], dtype='object')
```

And, the corresponding columns;

```
df1[df1.columns.difference(df2.columns)]

   month  year
0      1  2010
1      1  2012
2     11  2014
3     11  2014
4      9  2016
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do:
`[col for col in df1.columns if col not in df2.columns]` to find the columns of `df1` not in `df2` and the output gives you a list of columns name